# Color transitions when connecting MindMap nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

How to fix colors of extra edges connecting nodes, to make smooth transition?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=orange!40,
    level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}]

\node{Root}
    child [concept color=blue!30] { node (a) {Child A}
        child { node (aa) {Child AA}}
        child { node (ab) {Child AB}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Child B}
        child { node (ba) {Child BA}}
        child { node (bb) {Child BB}}
        child { node (bc) {Child BC}}
        child { node (bd) {Child BD}}
    }
    child [concept color=teal!40, grow=20] { node (c) {Child C}
        child { node (ca) {Child CA}}
    }
    child [concept color=purple!50] { node (d) {Child D}
        child [concept color=green!40] { node (da) {DA}}
        child [concept color=green!40] { node (db) {DB}}
    };
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw [circle connection bar]
      (aa) edge (db)
      (da) edge (ca)
      (c)  edge (bc)
      (a)  edge (ba) edge (da) edge (ca)
      (d)  edge (bd);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the switch from one colour to another. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=orange!40,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}]

  \node{Root}
  child [concept color=blue!30] { node (a) {Child A}
    child { node (aa) {Child AA}}
    child { node (ab) {Child AB}}
  }
  child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Child B}
    child { node (ba) {Child BA}}
    child { node (bb) {Child BB}}
    child { node (bc) {Child BC}}
    child { node (bd) {Child BD}}
  }
  child [concept color=teal!40, grow=20] { node (c) {Child C}
    child { node (ca) {Child CA}}
  }
  child [concept color=purple!50] { node (d) {Child D}
    child [concept color=green!40] { node (da) {DA}}
    child [concept color=green!40] { node (db) {DB}}
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l in
    {%
      aa/blue!30/db/green!40,
      da/green!40/ca/teal!40,
      c/teal!40/bc/yellow!30,
      a/blue!30/ba/yellow!30,
      a/blue!30/da/green!40,
      a/blue!30/ca/teal!40,
      d/purple!50/bd/yellow!50%
    }
    \path (\i) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (\j) to (\l)] (\k);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: colour transitions]

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this without having to specify the actual colors?